# How to batch process videos through Deshaker in VirtualDub?

Tags: stabilisation, virtualdub

I've just set up the latest versions of VirtualDub and the Deshaker plugin (both 64-bit versions in Windows 8.1 64-bit), and was able to follow the official Deshaker instructions to stabilise a video. However, I have several dozens videos to stabilise, so I'd like to batch process them.

I know VirtualDub has the Job Control window to prepare batch jobs, but the problem is that the Deshaker plugin requires two passes for each video file, and the first pass *does not* produce an output video file.

Internet searches did not reveal a way to batch Deshake videos. Does anyone here have instructions on how to achieve this with relative ease??? Thank you!

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170615195507/http://tipzorro.blogspot.no/2015/06/virtualdub-and-deshaker-in-batch-mode.html